# Compare JSON files in powershell

Tags: json, git, powershell

################File-1.json####################

```
{
      "aaa-prod-release-branch": {
        "value": "release/S1.1-000000T01"
      },
      "bbb-prod-release-branch": {
        "value": "release/S2.2-000000T02"
      },
      "ccc-prod-release-branch": {
        "value": "release/S3.3-000000T03"
      }
    }
```

################File-2.json####################

```
{
  "aaa-current-release-branch": {
    "value": "release/S1.1-000000T01"
  },
  "bbb-current-release-branch": {
    "value": "release/S2.2-000000T02"
  },
  "ccc-current-release-branch": {
    "value": "release/S3.3-000000T044"
  },
  "ddd-current-release-branch": {
    "value": "releases/R4.4-000000T04"
  }
}
```

I have two JSON files with the above contents. I need to compare these two files and get differences in powershell.

1. Only compare branch names for repos that exists in both files and get the branch names for that respective repo.

Ex: only compare aaa, bbb and ccc branches and NOT ddd since it does not exist in both files.

For each repo (aaa, bbb, ccc) value (that exists in both files) in file-1.json I need to compare the respective repo value in  File-2.json.

Example:
ccc-prod-release-branch (cc is repo name)  value is different in File-2.json. In this case get both branch values and repo name in this case **ccc**.

**release/S3.3-000000T03**

**release/S3.3-000000T044**

Then use the above values to clone ccc repo and compare these two branches. I need a way to do this in powershell.

For **ddd-current-release-branch** branch since it is new I want to just run a clone and get all the commits in that branch.

How can I do this in powershell script. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a decent starting point. I'm making some assumptions about your real naming conventions and such:

```sh
# Get your json text as an object
$json1 = Get-Content '.\file1.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
$json2 = Get-Content '.\file2.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

# Your json example comes in as a single object with each repo as a property, which isn't what you want:

aaa-prod-release-branch         bbb-prod-release-branch         ccc-prod-release-branch        
-----------------------         -----------------------         -----------------------        
@{value=release/S1.1-000000T01} @{value=release/S2.2-000000T02} @{value=release/S3.3-000000T03}
```

So convert the awkward json to lists of powershell objects:

```
$prod = Foreach ($repo in $json1.psObject.Properties) {
  [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    repoName    = $repo.Name -replace '-prod-release-branch'
    branchName  = $repo.Name
    releaseName = $repo.Value.Value
}}
$current = Foreach ($repo in $json2.psObject.Properties) {
  [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    repoName    = $repo.Name -replace '-current-release-branch'
    branchName  = $repo.Name
    releaseName = $repo.Value.Value
}}

# Outputs:

repoName branchName              releaseName           
-------- ----------              -----------           
aaa      aaa-prod-release-branch release/S1.1-000000T01
bbb      bbb-prod-release-branch release/S2.2-000000T02
ccc      ccc-prod-release-branch release/S3.3-000000T03
```

Then it's much easier to compare them however you need:

```sh
# Example: list all differences
Compare-Object $prod $current -Property 'ReleaseName' -IncludeEqual -PassThru

repoName branchName                 releaseName             SideIndicator
-------- ----------                 -----------             -------------
aaa      aaa-prod-release-branch    release/S1.1-000000T01  ==           
bbb      bbb-prod-release-branch    release/S2.2-000000T02  ==           
ccc      ccc-current-release-branch release/S3.3-000000T044 =>           
ccc      ccc-prod-release-branch    release/S3.3-000000T03  <=           
ddd      ddd-current-release-branch releases/R4.4-000000T04 =>           

# Example: repos that need full clone
$ToClone = $current | Where { $_.repoName -NotIn $prod.repoName }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer above. Sorry for the late comment as I had health issues.

Comment: One follow up question - How can compare the values for the branches that are only present in file1.json. In this case only compare the values for aaa, bbb and ccc in file2.json.  Branch ddd should be ignored.   Only ccc branch should be cloned.

Comment: @Spartan87 I think the basic result you want would be done by filtering the objects you want to compare with `where-object` like: `Compare-Object $prod ($current | where-object repoName -ne 'ddd') -IncludeEqual -PassThru`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. My idea here is to only compare the values of repo names in file.json to the respective repo names in file2.json.  In this case after comparison the ccc branch value is different so I want to clone ccc repo and compare branches( in file.json and file2.json) to get the different commits. If there is a newer repo in file2.json that does not exist in file1.json then I want to ignore it and not compare it.  Appreciate your help on this.